Variance of linear combination of random variables conditional on another linear combination of the same random variables?
Suppose $X=\sum_{i=1}^nb_iX_i$ and $Y=w\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$. Is the following correct?
Conditional variance: $Var[X|Y]=\sum_{i=1}^nb_i^2Var[X_i|Y]+\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{i\neq j}^nb_ib_jCov[X_i,X_j|Y],$
with:
$Var[X_i|Y]=Var[X_i]-(Cov[X_i,w\sum_{i=1}^nX_i])^2Var[w\sum_{i=1}^nX_i]^{-1}=\sigma^2-\frac{(w\sigma^2(1+\rho(n-1)))^2}{w^2\sigma^2n(1+\rho(n-1))}=\sigma^2(1-\frac{1+\rho(n-1)}{n}),$
$Cov[X_i,X_j|Y]=Cov[X_i,X_j]-Cov[X_i,w\sum_{i=1}^nX_i]Var[w\sum_{i=1}^nX_i]^{-1}Cov[w\sum_{i=1}^nX_i,X_j]=\rho\sigma^2-\frac{(w\sigma^2(1+\rho(n-1)))^2}{w^2\sigma^2n(1+\rho(n-1))}=\sigma^2(\rho-\frac{1+\rho(n-1)}{n}),$
where the second inequality in the two expressions above follows from my given variance-covariance matrix of joint normally distributed and correlated random variables $X_i$ (see my comment).
Putting all together:  $Var[X|Y]=\sigma^2((1-\frac{1+\rho(n-1)}{n})\sum_{i=1}^nb_i^2+(\rho-\frac{1+\rho(n-1)}{n})\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{i\neq j}^nb_ib_j).$
Is my derivation correct? If so, can I further simplify the expression I obtained?

Are you assuming that the $X_i$ have a joint normal distribution?

yes, I edited my OP by adding "joint". The $n$ by $n$ variance-covariance matrix looks like $V$ in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/257722/inverse-of-a-matrix#comment729432_257722
